# Is there any documentation available for dynamic linker functions for glibc 6?

Tags: c, linux, compiler-construction, linker, glibc

I need it because I have to modify the linker, specifically that part where it resolves the symbols in plt section and updates them in GOT.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by modifying the dynamic linker? Maybe you are just looking for `dlopen()` et al.?

Comment: @H2CO3 I need to modify the "resolver" function which resolves the plt call symbols in GOT. Basically I want to modify this resolver function and get the address that it resolves and use it some where else. Can you suggest some good resources to understand the internals for the same (sort of documentation or anything will do) thanks

Comment: Isn't that part of ld-linux.so ?

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort he wants to modify internals of `ld-linux.so`

Comment: Yup, I initially misread.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've already posted in my previous answer to your question, [this page is great](http://web.archive.org/web/20120922073347/http://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~charngda/elf.html).

Read it carefully — there is also a number of references and books in the beginning (*Useful books and references* heading).

You may also want to look at *Linkers and Loaders* by Levine for reference.

Comment: Actually I am trying to find the documentation for the code of the linker specially rhe resolver function in elf/dl-runtime.c. I have one question for the very first time when the resolver function resolves the actual absolute address of the called function, does it jumps to that address from within the resolver function or reads the updated absolute address from GOT entry and then jump to it.(for the first time only, I know after that it reads directly from GOT and jumps).

Comment: @abhi In case you're looking for "clean and proven documentation" you're probably not going to find it. What you have to do is read the posted page thoroughly and poke the code in debugger.

Comment: @abhi as for question, it's very implementation-specific. I'd bet on leaving straight from resolver, since address is already known there. But you'll be better off disassembling the `.plt` section of ELF for your platform and looking there. Or even stepping through it in debugger.

Comment: The part *.plt section* describes it in pretty detailed way and mentions the source files to look at.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will go through it.